# Getting started on FIX protocol with PHP sockets

Tags: php, sockets, protocols, fix-protocol

I have pretty basic knowledge of PHP sockets and the FIX protocol altogether. I have an account that allows me to connect to a server and retrieve currency prices.

I adapted this code to connect and figure out what I receive back from the remote server:

```
$host = "the-server.com";
    $port = "2xxxx";

    $fixv = "8=FIX.4.2";
    $clid = "client-name";
    $tid = "target-name";

    $fp = fsockopen($host, $port, $errno, $errstr, 30);
    if (!$fp) {
        echo "$errstr ($errno)<br />\n";
    } else {
        $out = "$fixv|9=70|35=A|49=$clid|56=$tid|34=1|52=20000426-12:05:06|98=0|108=30|10=185|";
        echo "\n".$out."\n";
        fwrite($fp, $out);
        while (!feof($fp)) {
            echo ".";
            echo fgets($fp, 1024);
        }
        fclose($fp);
    }
```

and I get nothing back. The host is good because I'm getting an error when I use a random one.
Is the message I'm sending not generating a reply ?

I might not be very good at finding things in Google but I could not find any simple tutorial on how to do this with php (at least nothing that puts together fix and php).

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: More info on this 
http://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2011/02/fix-protocol-session-or-admin-messages.html
I believe I followed the logon instructions properly so I guess either my code doesn't read the reply properly or is there a different issue...

Comment: Hi NickO, did you get this to work in the end?

Comment: I think that project requirements changed at that time and we found a different way to do it.

Comment: Actually is PHP capable to communicate with FIX server ?

Answer (score 4):

FIX separator character is actually `'\001'` not `'|'`, so you have to replace that when sending.

Some links for you:

- [FIX protocol](http://www.fixprotocol.org/) - formal specs
- [Onixs FIX dictionary](http://www.onixs.biz/tools/fixdictionary/) - very useful site for tag lookup

#### Edit 0:

From that same [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fix_protocol) article you mention:

> The message fields are delimited using the ASCII 01  character.
> ...
> Example of a FIX message : Execution Report (Pipe character is used to represent SOH character) ...

#### Edit 1:

Couple more points:

- Tag 9 holds message length without tags 8 (type), 9 (length), and 10 (checksum).
- Tag 10, checksum, has to be a modulo 256 sum of ASCII values of all message characters including all `SOH` separators, but not including the tag 10 itself (I know, it's stupid to have checksums on top of TCP, but ...)

Comment: The message I built was checked with
http://www.validfix.com/fix-analyzer.html
8=FIX.4.2|9=53|35=A|49=a|56=b|34=1|52=20000426-12:05:06|98=0|108=30|10=237|

Comment: also here is an example of a FIX message using the  | separator http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FIX_protocol

Comment: I am talking about the wire format. You might also want to include `fflush()` after the write.

Comment: Just noticed that after you mentioned it. I'm reformatting the message but my question is still - even if that message is wrongly formatted, should I not get something, anything back?

Comment: That's totally server implementation dependent. I saw places that just drop your connection on malformed message. Also, don't forget to flush the output.

Comment: I must miss something because I am unable to get any sort of message back from the server. I have my simple code here - http://pastebin.com/9sxYXgyd . Any ideas?

Comment: line 26 in the above code has been updated to read 108 instead of 08

Comment: The only thing wrong I see is that you are missing `SOH` after the checksum, i.e. append `'\001'` to the very end of the message. Other then that - try sending some pre-canned message to the server with, say, `nc`. Do you get anything back? Pull out `wireshark` and check what's going on on the wire.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is the use of `fgets(...)`, it is expecting a `\n` which does not exists in this FIX protocol.

On top of that, an expected length of 1024 is specified, which is a length that the response is unlikely to exceed.

To cap it off, since the server doesn't terminate the connection, `fgets(...)` hangs there "forever"